# How to retrieve information on a specific button when clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a film review site where users can search for the title of a film and when entered, a list of films matching the entered title will appear.

I made it so that each film and its corresponding information is contained within a button. I want to add an event listener to the film buttons that will listen to when the button is clicked and retrieve an image link of the movie poster from that specific button that was clicked and plug it into a text field with the ID of "imageSrc". The problem is that currently, it only retrieves the image link of the last film button that is displayed on the page rather than retrieving a specific film button I clicked and the last image link is plugged into the text field "imageSrc" right after entering the search (no film buttons were clicked, it just automatically plugs in the image link associated with the last film result displayed).

```
function FilmCard({ film }) {
  function displaySearchResults({ film }) {
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      if (film.results[`${i}`]) {
        results +=
          `<button class='singleFilmCards' onclick=${(document.getElementById(
            "imageSrc"
          ).value = film.results[`${i}`].image)}>` +
          "<div class='film-wrapper'>" +
          `<img src="${film.results[`${i}`].image}">` +
          "<h2>" +
          film.results[`${i}`].title +
          "</h2>" +
          "<h3>" +
          film.results[`${i}`].description +
          "</h3>" +
          "<div>" +
          "</button>";
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
  if (!film) return <></>;
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="FilmList"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: displaySearchResults({ film }),
        }}
      >
        {/* <img alt="Movie Posters" src={film.results[0].image} />
        <h2>{film.results[0].title}</h2>
        <p>{film.results[0].description}</p> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the index variable `i` in your loop will always have value of 5 in all the `onclick`s. There is very good reason why setting a pure html in react is done with the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop - to let the developer know that he/she's doing something that shouldn't be done (there are cases when it's necessary, extremely rare though...)

What you should do, is to make the button into it's own component and handle the events via react event callbacks.

You could try something like this:

```
function FilmButton({ result, onImageChange }) {
    return (
        <button
            className="singleFilmCards"
            onClick={() => onImageChange(result.image)}
        >
            <div className="film-wrapper">
                <img src={result.image} />
                <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                <h3>{result.description}</h3>
            </div>
        </button>
    );
}

function FilmCard({ film }) {
    const handleImageChange = (imageUrl) => {
        document.getElementById("imageSrc").value = imageUrl;
    };

    if (!film) {
        return <></>;
    }

    return (
        <div className="FilmList">
            {film.results.map((result, index) => (
                <FilmButton
                    key={index}
                    result={result}
                    onImageChange={handleImageChange}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

...in fact, you definitely might want to consider also rewriting the `document.getElementById("imageSrc").value = imageUrl` in such way, that you won't be manipulating the DOM directly. Because this completely bypasses React.js. There are many ways you rewrite this to use React - from passing the new imageUrl via prop callback into higher component (same as the `onImageChange` in my example), to using a React context (context would probably be an overkill though :)